# Distinct Count x and Grouping by Date y

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to get from the following data in an SQL database

```
date                    |    user   |
(DateTime)              |   (string)|
--------------------------------------------------
2013-06-03 13:24:54.013 |     3     |
2013-06-04 13:25:54.013 |     5     |
2013-06-04 13:26:54.013 |     3     |
2013-06-04 13:27:54.013 |     3     |
```

a list in the form

```
date        | DistinctCountUser
---------------------------------
2013-06-03  | 1
2013-06-04  | 2
```

I've tried several ways to do this with linq but always end up with a) not the result I expected or b) a linq exception.

Comment: Are you using Linq to SQL or EF?

Comment: Can you show a couple (or even just one) of the several ways you tried?

Comment: Sorry for missing info, I'm using Linq to Entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Entity Framework, then you should use [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) to get date part of date time field:

```
 from x in context.TableName
 group x by EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.date) into g
 select new {
     date = g.Key,
     DistinctCountUser = g.Select(x => x.user).Distinct().Count()
 }
```

Otherwise use @KingKong answer

Comment: The `Distinct` you use looks like `DistinctBy`?

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = input.GroupBy(x=>x.date.Date,(key,x)=> new {
                      date = key,
                      DistinctCountUser = x.Select(e=>e.user).Distinct().Count()
                   });
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately default EF provide cannot translate Date property getting. But that is completely OK with old Linq to SQL

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use query expression when grouping in Linq. Query Expressions may be easier to read in some cases and I find grouping to be one of them.

```
from thing in things
group thing by thing.date.Date into g
select new {
    Date = g.Key,
    DistinctCountUser = g.Select(x => x.user).Distinct().Count()
}
```